# error er_con_count_error too many connections express mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, api, express, pool

I am programming in angular and create an api server in express, I have a little problem when I have been programming and making requests in the API for hours. What happens is what arrives as a maximum number of requests and throws me an error.

The operation is fine nothing fails me, it is only after a while that I get that error and for that reason the database is disconnected and my frontend in angular works.

After a while the server throws this error at me

```
(node:10356) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR: Too many connections
    at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError (C:\xampp\htdocs\sinapsisuao\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:47:14)
    at Handshake.ErrorPacket (C:\xampp\htdocs\sinapsisuao\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Handshake.js:123:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\xampp\htdocs\sinapsisuao\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (C:\xampp\htdocs\sinapsisuao\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (C:\xampp\htdocs\sinapsisuao\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:43:10)
    at Protocol.write (C:\xampp\htdocs\sinapsisuao\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\sinapsisuao\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:88:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\sinapsisuao\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:283:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:264:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:219:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (C:\xampp\htdocs\sinapsisuao\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (C:\xampp\htdocs\sinapsisuao\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:51:23)
    at PoolConnection.connect (C:\xampp\htdocs\sinapsisuao\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:116:18)
    at Pool.getConnection (C:\xampp\htdocs\sinapsisuao\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\Pool.js:48:16)
    at Pool.query (C:\xampp\htdocs\sinapsisuao\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\Pool.js:202:8)
    at Promise (C:\xampp\htdocs\sinapsisuao\server\node_modules\promise-mysql\lib\helper.js:26:45)
    at Promise._execute (C:\xampp\htdocs\sinapsisuao\server\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\debuggability.js:384:9)
    at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (C:\xampp\htdocs\sinapsisuao\server\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:518:18)
    at new Promise (C:\xampp\htdocs\sinapsisuao\server\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:103:10)
    at Pool.promiseCallback (C:\xampp\htdocs\sinapsisuao\server\node_modules\promise-mysql\lib\helper.js:8:16)
    at pool.query (C:\xampp\htdocs\sinapsisuao\server\node_modules\promise-mysql\lib\pool.js:57:32)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\sinapsisuao\server\build\controllers\facilitadorController.js:16:42
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (C:\xampp\htdocs\sinapsisuao\server\build\controllers\facilitadorController.js:5:58)
(node:10356) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:10356) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
GET /api/facilitadores - - ms - -
OPTIONS /api/facilitadores 204 0.126 ms - 0
(node:10356) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR: Too many connections
    at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError (C:\xampp\htdocs\sinapsisuao\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:47:14)
    at Handshake.ErrorPacket (C:\xampp\htdocs\sinapsisuao\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Handshake.js:123:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\xampp\htdocs\sinapsisuao\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (C:\xampp\htdocs\sinapsisuao\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (C:\xampp\htdocs\sinapsisuao\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:43:10)
    at Protocol.write (C:\xampp\htdocs\sinapsisuao\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\sinapsisuao\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:88:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\sinapsisuao\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:283:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:264:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:219:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
```

My code database is this:

```
import { createPool } from "promise-mysql";

import keys from "./keys";

export async function connect(){
    const connection = createPool(keys.database);    
    return connection;
}
```

And my index is:

```
import express, { Application } from "express";
import morgan from 'morgan';
import cors from 'cors';

import indexRoutes from './routes/indexRoutes';
import usersRoutes from './routes/users.Routes';
import emprendedorRoutes from './routes/emprendedor.Routes';
import facilitadorRoutes from "./routes/facilitador.Routes";
import consultoriaRoutes from "./routes/consultoria.Route";
import emprendimientoRoutes from "./routes/emprendimiento.Routes";
import calendarioRoutes from "./routes/calendar.Route";
import atencionRoutes from "./routes/atencion.Route";

class Server {
    public app: Application;

    constructor(){
        this.app = express();
        this.config();
        this.routes();
    }
//configuracion
    config(): void{
        this.app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
        this.app.use(morgan("dev"));
        this.app.use(cors());
        this.app.use(express.json());
        this.app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
    }
//rutas
    routes(): void {
        this.app.use('/',indexRoutes);
        this.app.use('/api/users',usersRoutes);
        this.app.use('/api/emprendedores', emprendedorRoutes);
        this.app.use('/api/facilitadores', facilitadorRoutes);
        this.app.use('/api/consultorias', consultoriaRoutes );
        this.app.use('/api/emprendimientos', emprendimientoRoutes );
        this.app.use('/api/calendar', calendarioRoutes);
        this.app.use('/api/atencion', atencionRoutes)

    }
//inicia servidor
    start(): void{
        this.app.listen(this.app.get('port'), ()=>{
            console.log('Server on port', this.app.get('port'));
            console.log("Conectados a la BD");


        });
    }
}

const server = new Server();

server.start();
```

Someone, who can help me with this problem, only appears when I have been programming for a while.

Answer (score 1):

[max_connect_errors](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connect_errors) defaults to 100. When you are using connection pools this means a number of sparatic errors can quickly add up to 64 resulting in the error experiences.

Solution part 1: remove the connection pooling. Simple per connection is ok.

Solution part 2: increase max_connect_errors to its documented maximium

Solution part 3: try to identify some of the errors that occur and see if they are programmatic mistakes or transient network connection problems.